# css behaving differently on local host and heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

In my app, I am pushing the local project to Heroku, but for some reasons it gives different results on the Heroku.

on local host [image: this is on the localhost] and [image: this is on the heroku server]

So I am not able to understand why this is happening.

I tried running `heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but this doesn't help.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: yes Mohit, Rails 4.0.2

Comment: Yes I did that as well..

Comment: @MohitBhasi yes I have this in my gemfile

` group :production, :staging do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end`

Comment: I didn't get your point here @MohitBhasi

Comment: @Sontya Did that as well. :-/

Comment: can you guys please answer as an answer, too much comments here will mess it up

Comment: posted an answer , check it out